# Take JSON response and transform it to pass around application

Tags: nestjs

In my NestJS app, I'm making a REST request to a remote API I do not have control over. The REST API has a response containing JSON, a large object, most of which I do not need. Let's assume hypothetically that we have a JSON object that looks like the following:

```
{
"foo": [
    1,
    2,
    3
],
"bar": {
    "nested": {
        "some_key": "some_val"
    }
}
```

}

What if in this case, after I make a request to this API, I want to pass around only a subset of the above. Something like a `NestedDto` that would look like the following:

```
import { IsNotEmpty, IsString } from 'class-validator'

export class NestedDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  someKey: string
}
```

What is the best way for me to take the data that's being returned from the REST API and transform it into the above-using tools that NestJS offers? I want to be able to take responses from remote APIs and pass said data around inside of my NestJS app using my interface specifications.

Comment: Are you using the provided Http Service from NestJS, or are you implementing your own? And if you are, are you using observables or the `.toPromise()` method? Just wanting to know how to structure code for an answer

Comment: Hi @JayMcDoniel I haven't used the Http Service provided by NestJS but I'm completely open to it. I was going to use something like Axios. Not doing anything fancy, just an unauthenticated HTTP GET request. No observables or anything. In my vanilla express.js app it's simply axios, then just munge the keys/data I want out of the response object and that's it. I want to improve on that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All right, if you're just using Axios with no special configuration, you could do what you are already doping in Express by just mapping the response down to what you want. If you want to get a little fancy with it you could always implement some sort of class decorated with [class-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) decorators and use a `plainToClass` method mixed with the [`@Transform()`](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#additional-data-transformation) decorator.

By the way, by default, NestJS provides an [HttpModule](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/http-module) that is a wrapper around Axios, but its responses are as [RxJS Observables](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html). If you decide to go with the observable route, you can use the observable operator `map` to do the mapping for you (you'll still have to provide mapping implementation though, like the `plainToClass` I mentioned above), but that is completely up to you.

Comment: Really wish there was better documentation for how to handle these HTTP responses that are wrapped as Observables. Thanks for the explanation though.